# Custom Rails Routes invalidating CanCan permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions, routes, cancan

I'm working on a project that has multiple kinds of users, each attached to an institution, and each with their own set of permissions. Recently, I went about changing the Rails Routes so that instead of passing the `:id` I'm passing a custom `:identifier` in the URL parameters for institutions. I had it working correctly, institutions were updating and loading correctly, etc. When I ran my spec tests however, I realized that the permissions were no longer working. For example, the most restricted level of users, Institutional_Users should not be able to load any Institution's show page except for their own and now they can see anyone's. I'm at a loss for how to fix this.

Below is my `Institutions_Controller`. The first `set_institution` method is the one that I wrote to handle the new parameter, the second is the original one.

```
class InstitutionsController < ApplicationController
  inherit_resources
  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_institution, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  #before_action :get_institution, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  include Blacklight::SolrHelper

  # DELETE /institutions/1
  # DELETE /institutions/1.json
  def destroy
    #@institution = set_institution
    name = @institution.name
    destroy!(notice: "#{name} was successfully destroyed.")
  end



  private
    def set_institution
      if params[:identifier].nil?
        @institution = current_user.institution
      elsif Institution.where(desc_metadata__identifier_tesim: params[:identifier]).empty?
        @institution = current_user.institution
        flash[:alert] = "That institution does not exist."
      else
        @institution = Institution.where(desc_metadata__identifier_tesim: params[:identifier]).first
      end
    end

    # If an id is passed through params, use it.  Otherwise default to show a current user's institution.
    #def set_institution
    #  @institution = params[:id].nil? ? current_user.institution : Institution.find(params[:id])
    #end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def build_resource_params
      params[:action] == 'new' ? [] : [params.require(:institution).permit(:name, :identifier)]
    end

end
```

I added this to my `Institution Model` so that it parameterizes correctly:

```
def to_param
  identifier
end
```

This is my `User Model` with some non-essential methods removed for length (I should not, we're using `Devise` for users

require 'bcrypt'

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Connects this user object to Hydra behaviors. 
  include Hydra::User

  # Connects this user object to Blacklights Bookmarks. 
  include Blacklight::User
  include Aptrust::SolrHelper

  # Connects this user object to Role-management behaviors. 
  include Hydra::RoleManagement::UserRoles

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :database_authenticatable,
  # :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :timeoutable

  validates :email, :phone_number, presence: true
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  validates :institution_pid, presence: true
  validate :institution_pid_points_at_institution

  # Custom format validations.  See app/validators
  validates :name, person_name_format: true, if: ->{ name.present? }
  validates :email, email: true

  # Handle and normalize phone numbers
  phony_normalize :phone_number, :default_country_code => 'US'

  validates :phone_number, :phony_plausible => true

  # This method assigns permission groups
  def groups
    super + institution_groups
  end

  def institution_groups
    if institutional_admin?
      ["Admin_At_#{institution_group_suffix}"]
    elsif institutional_user?
      ["User_At_#{institution_group_suffix}"]
    else
      []
    end
  end

  def institution_identifier
    institution = Institution.find(self.institution_pid)
    institution.identifier
  end

  # Blacklight uses #to_s on youruser class to get a user-displayable 
  # login/identifier for the account. 
  #
  # Method modified from the Blacklight default.
  def to_s
    name || email
  end

  # Roles are managed through the hydra-role-management gem.
  def is?(role)
    self.roles.pluck(:name).include?(role.to_s)
  end

  def admin?
    is? 'admin'
  end

  def institutional_admin?
    is? 'institutional_admin'
  end

  def institutional_user?
    is? 'institutional_user'
  end


  # Since an Institution is an ActiveFedora Object, these two objects cannot be related as normal (i.e. belongs_to)
  # They will be connected through the User.institution_pid.
  def institution
    @institution ||= Institution.find(self.institution_pid)
  rescue ActiveFedora::ObjectNotFoundError => e
    logger.warn "#{self.institution_pid} is set as the institution for #{self}, but it doesn't exist"
    @institution = NilInstitution.new
  end

  def institution_group_suffix
    clean_for_solr(institution_pid)
  end

  class NilInstitution
    def name
      "Deleted Institution"
    end

    def to_param
      'deleted'
    end

    def brief_name
      "Deleted Institution"
    end

    def users
      []
    end

    def intellectual_objects
      []
    end

    def bytes_by_format
      {}
    end
  end

  private

  def institution_pid_points_at_institution
    errors.add(:institution_pid, "is not a valid institution") unless Institution.exists?(institution_pid)
  end

end
```

And this is the `Ability Model` that sets up the user permissions. You can see where I attempted to add a new line to handle the identifier parameter without any luck.

```
class Ability
  include Hydra::Ability

  # customizing permissions as directed:
  # https://github.com/projecthydra/hydra-head/blob/master/hydra-access-controls/lib/hydra/ability.rb
  self.ability_logic +=[:admin_permissions, :institutional_admin_permissions, :institutional_user_permissions]


  def create_permissions
    # nop - override default behavior which allows any registered user to create
  end

  def admin_permissions
    if current_user.is? :admin
      can :manage, :all 
    end
  end

  def institutional_admin_permissions
    if current_user.is? :institutional_admin
      can :add_user, Institution, id: current_user.institution_pid
      can :add_user, Role, name: 'institutional_user'
      can :add_user, Role, name: 'institutional_admin'
      can [:read, :update, :destroy], User, institution_pid: current_user.institution_pid
      can [:create], User
      can :generate_api_key, User, id: current_user.id
      can [:read, :update], Institution, pid: current_user.institution_pid
      can :create, GenericFile, :intellectual_object => { :institution_id => current_user.institution_pid }
      can :create, IntellectualObject, institution_id: current_user.institution_pid
    end
  end

  def institutional_user_permissions
    if current_user.is? :institutional_user
      can :manage, User, id: current_user.id
      can :read, Institution, pid: current_user.institution_pid
      #can :read, Institution, identifier: current_user.institution_identifier
    end
  end

end
```

If I missed something, or there's any other code I need to add, please let me know. Thanks!

EDIT:

I added this line to my `Institution Controller` `set_institution` method:

```
authorize! [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy], @institution
```

The new method looks like this:

```
def set_institution
  if params[:institution_identifier].nil?
    @institution = current_user.institution
  elsif Institution.where(desc_metadata__institution_identifier_tesim: params[:institution_identifier]).empty?
    @institution = current_user.institution
    flash[:alert] = "That institution does not exist."
  else
    @institution = Institution.where(desc_metadata__institution_identifier_tesim: params[:institution_identifier]).first
    authorize! [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy], @institution
  end
end
```

Now, instead of being able to see all institutions, the Institutional Users can't see any of them if they visit the URL e.g. `localhost:3000/institutions/columbia`. Interestingly, though, when that happens the page redirects to the root, which happens to be the Institution show page. So Users can still access their own institution but only because of where that authorize statement is. It seems like adding the authorize line makes it impossible for institutional users to do anything while taking it away allows them to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar case i solved this using:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :find_by => :identifier
```

in the controller.

See: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions#custom-find